# Socket port already used in iOS?

Tags: ios, sockets, port

I use `CocoaAsyncSocket` in my application and try to discover devices and send message to them by `socket`. And the port is certain. Sometimes when i delete my application and reinstall it from `Xcode` my application can not do anything. I can not find and connect any device. I try to restart my iphone and the application can work order.

I think the process is not released and address already be used. But **how can i avoid this solution? Any resources used in my application will be releasd by iOS after my application be killed?**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When one device closes the TCP connection, it will be on TIME_WAIT state in 2MSL, during this time, it can't connect to the same socket pair (ip/port). It's TCP that forbid the connection, so even you reinstall your app, it won't work.

Comment: @KudoCC Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I use udp certain port, and have the same issue. My process is exit, but sometime the bind port cannot release. It is the iOS system bug?